# Android Studio The Way to Check How Much Code You Have Written So Far

Tags: android, android-studio

Just wondering is there a way to approximately (not 100% accurate required) check your experience (like how much code you've written so far) with Android Studio.

Comment: I suspect that you will need a plugin (Android Studio or Gradle) for that.

Comment: @AgentP Not for single project man.

Comment: Calling all `awk` professionals ...

Answer (score -1):

I think this is close to what I want:

Go to "Help" on the top menu bar -> "Productivity Guide".

[image]

Comment: It will be no where near to actual number of lines code... Although you don't want it 100% accurate but still the error margin goes beyond expected .... Which makes it unfeasible ... A line is different and a auto complete is different ...

Comment: @AgentP Actually I'm not care about how many lines of code, I am care about the total experience you have worked with Android Studio since the very beginning. Do you have better approach?

Comment: No, but you can't define experience in that way for sure ... better sentence would be how productive I am? And if you define experience as a number of years ... again it won't work with the tools we currently have ..